# console I/O in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, console

I just started doing some competitive programmning in objective C. There's a problem which I'm facing, most sites start with `main.m`

```
    int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {

     }
   }
```

I somehow learned how to get input  and use it. But today I tried a differnt work where

```
    void main()
    {
    }
```

when I tried `scanf("%s",str)` though I could read the first line of input. But I don't know how to start and how to get rest of lines.

I want to lean more about console input/output in iOS. Any help will be much appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a bit of a tutorial

[image: This is the console assuming you are using xcode. You can toggle it from top right side]

[image: The one in the middle]

If you right click any data structure for instance there'l be a first option "print description" another option with your code : NSLog(name of variable); for e.g for an array : NSLog(@"%@",myArray);

Lastly,Typing *po myarray* in the right half of the console (under lldb) would print out myArray's contents

Hope this helps! Cheers